# How to set the source of <script> to be an encrypted string?

Tags: javascript, encryption, base64

Suppose I want to include a script in my website:

```
<script src="files/myfunction.js"></script>
```

Now what I want to do is encrypt or encode, whatever you call it, the src i.e. "files/myfunction.js" and use that instead in the src of the script so that normal people can't see it. So that it looks something like:

```
<script src="zxcshdgfoiqjkfnasfgbkjsd"></script>
```

And the above script should still point to the myfunction.js file.
 I know it's not a good option but I just need answers that how can this be achieved? 
I've seen numerous examples on stackoverflow but none point to what I want specifically.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It can be achieved via server-side redirect. But who exactly do you want to protect it from and why? A browser still needs to access your script, so what exactly are you hoping to achieve by this?

Comment: What is the point? Anyone can still open and read that file

Comment: I just want it to be not readable by normal users. I know anyone can open it, I still want to make this thing work just learning purpose. Can I use an encrypted string in src of script? If yes then how?

Comment: Not in browser you can't. The `src` needs to be valid url. Whole idea makes no sense

Comment: You could write a script that loads this dynamically and *evals* it.

Comment: @Jonas w can u show me how?

Comment: @muddassir ahmed someone who will find the browsers console might still go onto tue *network* tab and find the code there... So no, its rather a half solution, thats why i havent answered

Comment: @jonas w Still, can u just give me what you know? I can take it ahead from there..

Comment: why downvote? I just want to achieve what I want to do with my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather *obfuscation* than *encryption* , you could load the file manually via ajax and eval it. If you use http://jquery.com, thats quite easy:

```
(function(j,e,a,u){
  j[a]({
   url:u,
   success:e
  });
})($,eval,["","j","x"].join("a"),"http://"+"ealagaoaaaaoaaaag".split("a").reverse().join("")+".com");
```

The upper code sends a request to google.com and evals the response ( which wont work because of same origin policy, it would if you change it to your own js script).